# .net web service hosted within my application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, web-services

I'm migrating an old Delphi application that I wrote into C#. The application is a datalogger that exposes logged data requests via a SOAP web service interface.

The web service is contained with the delphi graphical windows application, i.e. no need to run a web server like IIS, etc I just run the application and it's up and running under the hood.

I'm looking to do the same in my c# Windows form application, I can find loads of resources on writing web services that are ultimately hosted within IIS but am struggling to find a solution for a self contained web service within my application.

Does anyone have any suggestions or can point me towards any resources on this?

The web service does not neceserily have to be SOAP, REST is fine (in fact probably prefered).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into `WCF` Services.

- [Hosting and Consuming WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx)
- [Hosting WCF services in a Windows Forms Application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/wcfservice.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The System.Web.Hosting namespace allows you to host ASP.Net pages without using IIS within your applications. I have never used it to host web services but I found a tutorial that seems to provide a guide on doing this-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163879.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to host a service inside your application, it's possible with the `System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost` class. You need to learn WCF first, but that at least answers your question to get you started. If you have any further questions, leave me a comment or two and I'll update my answer to accommodate your inquiries.